# How to import TLB constants to java?

Tags: java, com, tlbinf32

I use groovy's scriptom. Scriptom's sources includes *.java files containing all the constants for Office, EI, etc. What program have been used to export them from tlb/dll/exe files? I need the same for MSProject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scriptom have 
[this script](http://svn.codehaus.org/groovy/modules/scriptom/trunk/oddsnends/typelib/ExtractTlbInfo.groovy)
It requires tlbinf32.dll, which is unavailable on windows 7
Other option is [JATLOM](http://swttocom.sourceforge.net/concepts/jatlom.html)